# Problems adding symbols in the scale (Bracket plugin)

Tags: plugins, visual-studio-code

I used to code in sublime, but i decided to migrate to VScode.
when I programmed in Sublibe i used brackethighlighter and that plugin has symbols on the scale.

[image]

But in VSCODE we just have that strange lines.

[image]

Theres any way to config that plugin? To be equal to the sublime.
Or other similar plugin.